# No JWT detected - Amazon Connect Chat

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, jwt, amazon-connect

I am integrating AWS Connect Chat with my app and I get this error:

`No JWT detected`

I have searched for this error everywhere but I have not come across it, does anyone know how I can go about it? Here's the code that introduces the error:

```
amazon_connect('authenticate', function(callback) {
      window.fetch('/support/token').then(res => {
       callback(res?.data);
      });
  });
```

For the token, I am using `JWT.encode` to get the token then I `Base64.urlsafe_encode64` the token. When it it's my route, I `Base64.urlsafe_decode64` the token first. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Any suggestions will be appreciated! Thanks.